# How to hide editor, but keep media library access

Tags: custom-post-types, editor

How do I hide the editor from a custom post type, but retain the ability to access the media library?

I have registered a custom post type and created a meta box for it that allows users to upload files. However, if I remove support for the editor with the register_post_type function, the media library will no longer load.

Comment: You can use `Adminimize`plugin that might help you.

Comment: Can you post your code so we can reproduce the issue? Note that in most cases, no code = no question.

Comment: Is it possible that, when removing (from the 'supports' array) the  editor option, you don't see the  "Add Media" button anymore because it belongs to [TinyMCE](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE)?

Comment: Well, actually, I still see the button, it just throws a Javascript error when it's clicked, saying that 'frames' is undefined. But I discovered that if I add thumbnail support to the supports array, the custom meta box can access the media library and the featured image box can be hidden via screen options which will work for me.

Comment: @cybmeta, I thought it was something very simple that I was just missing that everyone else knew, not a specific problem with my code. I would post, but I found a solution that works fine for my purposes. I'll try to post code in the future.

Comment: It can be simply but if you don't post code, we have to guess what is happening. For example, you said "I have created a meta box for it that allow users to upload files"; then I thought that meta box handles everything but then, in the comments, it seems that you use the default "Add Media" button. So, please, post your code; if you do it and we can reproduce the issue oursefl, you will get better answers and quickly. I've created metaboxes with media manager several times but never using the default "Add media" button and I never had that issue; do you see why the code is important?

Answer (score 0):

> The media_upload_tabs filter passes a single argument containing an
>   array of the tabs, you can unset() them to remove them.

The array looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [type] => From Computer
    [type_url] => From URL
    [gallery] => Gallery
    [library] => Media Library
)
```

to remove the media library tab:

```
function remove_media_library_tab($tabs) {
    unset($tabs['library']);
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'remove_media_library_tab');
```

If you only want to hide it on certain posts or post_types you can check the $_REQUEST or $_GET args. When using the 'Upload/Insert' links several points of data are passed along: `/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=28506&type=image&TB_iframe=1&width=640&height=581`

```
function remove_media_library_tab($tabs) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {
        $post_type = get_post_type($_REQUEST['post_id]);
        if ('post' == $post_type)
            unset($tabs['library']);
    }
        return $tabs;
}
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'remove_media_library_tab');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ehm, maybe my screen shows some different but this is what I read: _but **keep** media library access_ .

Comment: Thatnks for the response, but Charles is right, I'm looking to keep the media library.